# performance of lz77 compression on large random array

Tags: lz77

I have a large array of raw bytes. The byte array does not follow any patter and the byte values can be any value (random).The size of the array is 45000x5x400 bytes. And I have 1 second to encode. Will lz77 be feasible? And how should I choose the look up dictionary? Also what will be a good choice for number of bits to hold the relative index and the match length ?

Comment: You cannot compress truly random data.

Comment: The data is network traffic data like ip port etc values.

Comment: Ah, okay, so not completely random.

Comment: My doubt is can I hope a good amount of compression (40%) on real data? That depends on the data I know. But will there be enough repeatation on the packet values?